# Почему приложение обозначено "Есть реклама" если ее там нет?

Tags: google-play

В учебных целях написал небольшую игру и выложил в Play Market, в настройках обозначил как бесплатную. Почему в маркете написано, что в игре есть реклама?

Ссылка: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.infernal93.butilochka

Comment: Проверьте все настройки. Это не автоматическая плашка, скорее всего где-то неправильно указали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Зайдите на страницу своего приложения Google Play Console.
2. В левом меню раскройте пункт "Настройки страницы приложения" и выберите подпункт "Цены и распространение".
3. Найдите на открывшейся странице настройку "Есть реклама" и установите переключатель в положение "нет"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Нажмите кнопку "Опубликовать приложение" для применения новых настроек.

Comment: спасибо за знание) спросил на eng SO никто ничего сказать не смог